# condition.value in Terraform dynamic block picks only value

Tags: terraform

The locals contain the CloudFront IDs:

```py
locals {
  cf_ids = [
    "E1DZ7XXXXX",
    "E2M7SXXXXX",
    "E1VABXXXXX"
  ]
}
```

This is the data source to generate json policy:

```py
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "cf_policy_for_s3" {

  statement {
    sid     = "CloudFrontPermissions"
    effect  = "Allow"
    actions = ["s3:GetObject"]
    resources = [
      "arn:aws:s3:::xxxxxxxxxx/*"
    ]

    dynamic "condition" {
      for_each = local.cf_ids
      content {
        test     = "StringEquals"
        variable = "AWS:SourceArn"
        values = ["arn:aws:cloudfront::123456789:distribution/${condition.value}"]
      }
    }

    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["cloudfront.amazonaws.com"]
    }
  }
}
```

In the output, it picks up one ID only:

```py
+ Condition = {
    + StringEquals = {
        + "AWS:SourceArn" = [
            "arn:aws:cloudfront::123456789:distribution/E2M7SXXXXX"
          ]
      }
  }
```

Expected output:

```py
+ Condition = {
    + StringEquals = {
        + "AWS:SourceArn" = [
            "arn:aws:cloudfront::123456789:distribution/E1DZ7XXXXX",
            "arn:aws:cloudfront::123456789:distribution/E2M7SXXXXX",
            "arn:aws:cloudfront::123456789:distribution/E1VABXXXXX"
          ]
      }
  }
```

As the expected output describes, all CloudFront IDs should be added in the condition in the final JSON output.

I have been searching online, but I could not find anything.

I decided to use multiple conditions, which would be unnecessary as the values are the list containing many CF ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is trying to do this

```
+ Condition = {
    + StringEquals = {
        + "AWS:SourceArn" = [
            "arn:aws:cloudfront::123456789:distribution/E1DZ7XXXXX"
          ]
      }
  }
+ Condition = {
    + StringEquals = {
        + "AWS:SourceArn" = [
            "arn:aws:cloudfront::123456789:distribution/E2M7SXXXXX"
          ]
      }
  }
+ Condition = {
    + StringEquals = {
        + "AWS:SourceArn" = [
            "arn:aws:cloudfront::123456789:distribution/E1VABXXXXX"
          ]
      }
  }
```

But you need to generate only one `Condition`. So, try this:

```yaml
locals {
  cf_ids = [
    "E1DZ7XXXXX",
    "E2M7SXXXXX",
    "E1VABXXXXX"
  ]

  arns = [for s in local.cf_ids : "arn:aws:cloudfront::123456789:distribution/${s}"]
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "cf_policy_for_s3" {
  ...
   condition {
      test     = "StringEquals"
      variable = "AWS:SourceArn"
      values = local.arns
    }
  ...
}
```

Comment: This has worked very smoothly. Thank you so much Maria.